# Is there a way to set a validation and edit a long value in an editable Vaadin 8 Grid

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid, vaadin8

I have a Vaadin 8 Grid where I would like to set one column as editable. For this I have where `Food.calories` is a long (yes in this case it could be an int but keep in mind this is an example and my specific use case requires a long):

```
Binder<Food> binder = foodGrid.getEditor().getBinder();
TextField caloriesTextField = new TextField();
binder.forField(caloriesTextField)
        .withValidator(CustomCaloryValidator::isValidValue, "Must be valid a positive amount")
        .withConverter(new StringToCaloriesConverter("Must be an integer"))
        .bind(Food::getCalories, Food::setCalories);

// This line fails with the error because the types do not match.
foodGrid.addColumn(Food::getCalories, new NumberRenderer(myNumberFormat))
        .setEditorComponent(new TextField(), Food::setCalories);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and has the following error:

Inferred type 'C' for type parameter 'C' is not within its bound; should implement 'com.vaadin.data.HasValue'

I looked everywhere I could and couldn't find any example of anything beyond simple edits. The [demo sampler](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid/item-editor) did have a more complex example using a slider but I couldn't figure out how to extrapolate from that example...

I understand the error, it's trying to map a long to a String. However I can't find a way to add a converter to the addColumn to make it work...

Comment: Did you read the [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.editing)? There you find an example using a `Binder` (`grid.getEditor().getBinder()`) which can be used to validate and convert field values.

Comment: The compile error is caused by the mismatch between the column data type (`Long`) and the editor component which has value type `String` because it is a `TextField` implementing `HasValue<String>`. If you supply the editor component without `Binder` involved, you need a field that supports `Long` values. As far as I know there is no such field out-of-the-box. However, the better way is to use a `Binder` because you can validate and convert. This allows to use a `TextField` for `Long` input with the `StringToLongConverter`.

Comment: Yes I did read the documentation. I just didn't know that bind() is also a shortcut for forField(). Vaadin has great documentation it's just that most of the examples are simple use cases. The documentation states that it's possible but the example doesn't show how. It uses the shortcut bind() method. But if you look at the documentation: https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html they use forField() and then bind() in pretty much every example. Therefore I didn't catch that bind() also called forField() in the grid editing example.

Comment: It's also not as easy as that. When I tried it it still didn't work. It said the validator was an incorrect type compared to a form (Object instead of String) and the binding didn't work either when I used forField()

Comment: Try to swap the validator and converter line. The order is important because the validator needs the `Long` instead of the `String`.

Comment: Additionally your `Binder` should have the right generic type argument: `Binder<Food>`

Comment: It didn't work. What I don't get is that it works for my form by not when I try to edit a grid...

Comment: In other words if I copy and paste that code into a form (rather than grid.getEditor().getBinder()) the code works...

Comment: Is there a sample with working code somewhere that I can copy and paste showing the grid editing a number with a TextField anywhere?

Comment: The first error was that I didn't do "Binder<Food> binder =". In other words I didn't case the Binder. That being said I'm going to edit the question because I've now run into another error...

Comment: If you paste your code for the converter, validator and `Food` bean, I can try to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the main issue was that the Binder did not specify the generic type, it needed to be:

```
Binder<Food> binder = foodGrid.getEditor().getBinder();
```

And NOT:

```
Binder binder = foodGrid.getEditor().getBinder();
```

That being said there were several other gotchas. First when you do a `forField()` you need to keep track of that binding to be able to set it later with the column. This wasn't clear at all for me. Specifically you need to:

```
Binder.Binding<Food, Long> caloriesBinder = binder.forField(caloriesTextField)
        .withValidator(CustomCaloryValidator::isValidValue, "Must be valid a positive amount")
        .withConverter(new StringToCaloriesConverter("Must be an integer"))
        .bind(Food::getCalories, Food::setCalories);
```

I'm not 100% sure on the caloriesBinder because my code is different and this is an example, but you need that binding. You then take that binding and do:

```
foodGrid.getColumn("calories").setEditorBinding(caloriesBinding);
```

This allows the correct editor to work. This is in the documentation but the example is very simple so I missed that.

The next step which is extremely important depending on what you're displaying, is to add a renderer otherwise you can run into some weird issues. For example if you're using long to store a currency then you need to convert it to display a currency amount. Similarly if you're using a date then you probably also want to format it. You then need to add a renderer. The only way I could find how to do it without compilation errors (mismatched types) was:

```
((Grid.Column<Food, Long>)foodGrid.getColumn("calories")).setRenderer(new CaloriesRenderer());
```

Just for completeness you then need to enable the editor with:

```
foodGrid.getEditor().setEnabled(true);
```

Lastly, if the table is part of a bigger bean then you need to call `foodGrid.setItems()`, you cannot just rely on `binder.readBean()` because it cannot accept a list. So for example if instead of food the bean was a meal which consisted of a number of ingredients, then you could not do `binder.readBean(meal)` nor could you do `binder.readBean(meal.getIngredients)` even though you can do `binder.readBean(meal)` for the rest of the form. The only way I could make it work was to do:

```
binder.readBean(meal);
foodGrid.setItems(meal.getIngredients);
```